# How to use threading in Laravel to run stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, stored-procedures, laravel-4

I want to use php threads for asynchronously loading a function that executes a mysql stored procedure. The stored procedure takes a lot of time to load, so keeping it asynchronous is the only optimal solution, I found.

I have no idea on how to bring the threading inside Laravel. Laravel has queues but I want to do it directly in script with thread.

Comment: The [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) library provides the necessary helpers to work with threads in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

What i've done to approach a similar issue (I've done it in a sync command) is to create a class that extends from Thread and call it from the laravel code.

The class in your case might be something like this:

```
class LaravelWorker extends Thread
{
    private $object;

    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $object->runProcedure();
    }
}
```

And you can call it at your code such as this:

```
$object = new ObjectWithProcedure();
$threadedMethod = new LaravelWorker($object);
$threadedMethod->start();
```

If, for some reason, you need to wait until the $threadedMethod finishes, you can do

```
$threadedMethod->join();
(more_code...)
```

And the more_code section will only execute once $threadedMethod has ended.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Getting error "Unable to find the Thread "